# How to avoid the vite create react app build error

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

When I create a fresh react app with vite and ts, without touching any file, i run the first `npm install` to install the needed dependencies and then i run `npm run build` and I try to run it locally with live server and **it doesnt works by default**. The console shows the following errors:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/index.08ff9814.js net::ERR_ABORTED
> 404 (Not Found) index.html:1 Refused to apply style from
> 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/index.3fce1f81.css' because its MIME
> type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict
> MIME checking is enabled.

I found out that if you add in the generated `index.html` the `.` for folder management `src="/assets/index.08ff9814.js"` it works `src="./assets/index.08ff9814.js"` the same thing happens with the logo and the style file

Does anyone know how to fix this silly bug or why vite generates relative paths that way?

Comment: i [cannot reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-bb8nfs). What do you mean by *"directly entering the html file"*? Do you mean opening the `index.html` in the browser without a server? That would not work, as Vite builds an app that requires a server. What commands did you use to create the app?

Comment: Yes i mean opening the index.html, i didn't knew that vite requires a server, but when i open the app with live server it doesn't work either. To create the app ``npm create vite@latest`` --> React-ts

Comment: What "live server" are you using? It works fine in the demo with Vite's on preview server.

Answer (score 0):

It just doesnt work's with live server (unless you change the dist/index.html inports) but if you upload your app in a host like netlify or vercel it just works as normal